# Вопрос о микроразметке (schema.org)

Tags: schema.org, микроразметка

Обращаюсь к тем, кто вообще сталкивался с микроразметкой, потому что знаю, что далеко не все её внедряют себе на сайты. Есть карточка товара, в ней есть всё согласно требованиям, кроме цены. Вместо цены там форма с формулировкой "позвоните для уточнения цены" - требование заказчика, ибо цены постоянно меняются. 
Так вот в чём вопрос, если валидатор от Яндекса ругается на то, что нету параметра "offer" - "цены", то всё так и оставить? Или лучше вообще не внедрять эту разметку?

Answer (score 2):

Может быть для автора уже не актуально, но возможно кто-нибудь наткнётся.

Согласно документации [Schema.org](https://schema.org/Offer) цена в предложении является обязательным. Вы можете не указывать цену, тогда Google или Яндекс просто не учёт разметку на этой странице.

Если у всего товара нет цены, то смысла тогда в разметки нет. Если у нескольких товаров нет цены, а у остальных есть, то будет лучшим оставить разметку.